# Unable to access secret from Secrets Manager

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-secret-manager

I've added some secrets to the Secret Manager but I get the following error trying to access them at runtime:

```
rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: compute: Received 500 `Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform
```

This is an old app I'm setting up again so I must have missed something in the permissions. I'm accessing the keys via the full path with the project id and the key name.

I've run `gcloud app describe` and verified that the `serviceAccount` listed there has the `Owner` Role. I've also added `Owner` to the App engine default service account. I've tried the specific Secret Manager Accessor role as well.

**Update:**
The service matches the golang example in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/samples/secretmanager-access-secret-version) for accessing a secret. It's using the standard google libraries for create a client and requests. I am not explicitly configuring authentication so the app should be using the service account as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically).

The path for the secret looks valid:

```
projects/<my-project-id>/secrets/MY_SECRET/versions/latest
```

The error message suggests it's missing a cloud-platform scope but I don't see any specific configuration for this since it's Google App Engine.

**Update 2:**
I've pushed a [repo](https://github.com/massfords/secrets-manager-test-golang) that recreates this. It uses the sample code from google for accessing a secret and fails with the same error about the cloud-platform scope.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#access), _accessing a secret version requires the Secret Manager Secret Accessor role_ (`roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor`) for the App Engine service account of your application. Also, could you show an example of the code you're using to access the Secret Manager to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The `Owner` role includes all permissions including the secretAccessor. The code matches the google samples and hasn't changed since it worked under the old project. I need to spin up a new test project that just reads a secret. It must be environmental.

Comment: Did you had any chance to test on a brand new project? From the test I've done on your repo, works fine for me. Therefore I agree with you that it probably could be environmental.

Comment: @RogelioMonter thank you for trying out my repo. I spun up a new project and tested with that repo prior to sharing it here. It failed the same way my existing project under the same account failed. I **have not** tried to create a new project under a new account. That's the only thing different in these tests at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshooting your app, I would suggest to do the following:

To be sure that the code you deploy to App Engine is running with the desired account, I suggest [Passing credentials using code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code) and *explicitly point to your service account file in code*.

```
./project-folder
├── test.go
├── service-account-credentials.json
├── ...
```

With a new project folder, [create a service account key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20service%20account%20key) and save in the folder.

Use the following code to test that your service account has the proper permissions, to discard that the problem is App Engine not using the proper account. You can check your App Engine logs in case something goes wrong.

```go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    secretmanager "cloud.google.com/go/secretmanager/apiv1"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    secretmanagerpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/secretmanager/v1"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

// Your Project ID
const projectId = "project-id"
// Name of your secret
const secret = "secret"

func main() {
    // Path to your secret
    // The version can be a version number as a string (e.g. "5") or an
    // alias (e.g. "latest").
    name := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/secrets/%s/versions/latest", projectId, secret)
    
    ctx := context.Background()
    
    // Explicitly reads credentials from the specified path.
    // Create the client.
        client, err := secretmanager.NewClient(ctx,
        option.WithCredentialsFile("service-account-key.json"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create secretmanager client\n")
        if s, ok := status.FromError(err); ok {
            log.Println(s.Message())
            for _, d := range s.Proto().Details {
                log.Println(d)
            }
        }
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Build the request.
    req := &secretmanagerpb.AccessSecretVersionRequest{
        Name: name,
    }
    
    // accessSecretVersion accesses the payload for the given secret version if one exists.
    // Call the API.
    result, err := client.AccessSecretVersion(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to access secret version\n")
        if s, ok := status.FromError(err); ok {
            log.Println(s.Message())
            for _, d := range s.Proto().Details {
                log.Println(d)
            }
        }
    }



    // WARNING: Do not print the secret in a production environment - this snippet
    // is showing how to access the secret material.
    log.Printf("Plaintext: %s\n", string(result.Payload.Data))

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `<h1>For testing purposes only.</h1>
        <h2>Do not use in production enviroments</h2>
        <p>Your secret is shown on Logs.<p>`)
    })

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    fmt.Printf("Starting server at port %s\n", port)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

As mentioned, your service account must be using the [`Owner`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions) role that grants permissions to the Secret Manager in order to access to the secret in Secret Manager.

See also

- [Passing credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually)
- [Cloud APIs errors](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors)
- [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#secretmanager)

Comment: See my update where I note that I am not configuring the service credentials in the application. The app uses the service accounts identity as linked above. Your example above relies on the service credentials being configured in a file.